# Reduction of α,β-unsaturated nitro compounds

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox, nitro-compounds, amines

Would it be possible to reduce a α,β-unsaturated nitro compound to a saturated amine using for example $\ce{NaBH4}$? I know these kind of compounds will be reduced by hydrogenation using a $\ce{Pt/C}$ catalyst, $\ce{LiAlH4}$ or freshly prepared Raney Nickel, but I'm looking for a reducing agent that is easier to handle than those.

The book from which I'm learning, [Clayden et al.](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Organic-Chemistry-Jonathan-Clayden/dp/0198503466), does not really go into much detail on reduction of nitro compounds or unsaturated alkanes, other than that hydrogenation is a good approach to both and that the nitro group is one of the most easily reduceable functional groups. But how about a α,β unsaturated compounds then? How would I asses whether some reducing agent is able to reduce both simultaneously?

Comment: Perhaps you could have a look at :
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S004040390060148X

Comment: @jori I feel that the electron-withdrawing nature of the nitro group would make reduction with electrophilic reducing agents less likely but reduction with nucleophilic reducing agents more likely. Perhaps something strong such as LAH would do the trick.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not aware of a $\ce{NaBH4}$-based reduction of nitroalkenes to saturated amines, such as in:

[image: nitroalkene-to-sat.amine]

It is however possible to reduce nitroalkenes to saturated hydroxylamines using $\ce{BH3*THF}$ in the presence of catalytic amounts of $\ce{NaBH4}$. ([DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/jo00201a030))

If there's a chance to perform the desired transformation in one step via catalytic hydrogenation at normal pressure: **go for it!**

The handling of these reactions is nothing to be afraid of.

Typically, I performed hydrogenations in a standard 2- or 3-neck flasks and used ordinary balloons (think childrens' birthday) as gas storage. **Advice**: Stuff a piece of rubber tube into the inlet of the balloon and secure it with teflon tape.

- Either attach this to the glas olive of a valve attached to your flask
- or take a plastic syringe, cut off the base, stuff the the plastic cylinder into the rubber tube. Fill the balloon and attach a needle. Hydrogen may now be fed to your reaction mixture through a rubber septum cap.

---

**UPDATE**

I still doubt that the intended reduction by $\ce{NaBH4}$ is possible.

There is however another established route from $\alpha,\beta$-unsaturated nitroalkenes to amines which is worth to be mentioned:

Condensation products of aromatic aldehydes and nitroalkenes are reduced by iron in hydrochloric (or acetic) acid to the corresponding arylalkanones.

[image: reduction of arylalkanone]

These ketones can be converted to primary amines by **reductive amination** in methanol (or ethanol) in the presence of (excess) ammonia and, of course, hydrogen over Raney Nickel or Urushibara Nickel.

[image: reductive amination]

In the course of this reaction, the imine intermediate is *in situ* reduced to the desired primary amine.

The resulting amines are valuable precursors in the synthesis of natural products: Their conversion to imines or amides and subsequent *Pictet-Spengler* or *Bischler-Napieralski* cyclisations furnish tetrahydro- and 3,4-dihydroisoquinolines.

Comment: You mean like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PC4DT4ier2Q ? $\ce{BH3}$ is impossible to handle safely in amateur setting, way worse I think than Raney Nickel or even LAH. Perhaps Urushibara nickel will do the job, which is said to be more easy to handle (read non-pyrophoric). For small scale reactions your idea with the balloon might work well indeed. Do you have a link to a somewhat more extensive description of the technique?

Comment: I agree with this, you should not avoid catalytic hydrogenation... Nitro groups are easily reduced, but NaBH4 alone won't make it. Another nice feature of sodium borohydride!

Comment: I also saw relatively cheap Parr hydrogenators on eBay (some in the range of 400-600$). These things seem pretty heavy and loud and I'm a bit weary of the explosion hazards, but they can be used for larger amounts and require less work. What level of expertise is required to handle such things anyway? Do you need special training? (see e.g. http://ebay.to/1BMFHHP)

Comment: @Jori Yes, like in the video, although I usually evacuated the flask through a larger diameter using a piece like [this](http://www.rettberg.biz/uploaded/image/shop/rettberg/schliffbauteile/134039514.jpg). In the video, the tube attached to the balloon looks like a commercially available piece, I always chopped something together from material from the lab drawers ;) The balloon technique works nice, but I never did this on a kilogram scale. Btw, Raney Nickel isn't that bad as long as you handle it with care and keep it wet. It really is pyrophoric :D

Comment: @Jori The ebay offer doesn't seem to include the reaction flask. You might want to decide for yourself whether you want to run a hydrogenation at 60 psi (4 bar).

Comment: @KlausWarzecha Thank you for the edit, that is very helpful. Can you comment on why $\ce{Fe/HCl}$ reduces the $\alpha,\beta$-unsaturated nitroalkene to a keton instead of a saturated nitroalkane or a (un)saturated amine? What exactly do you mean by: "You might want to decide for yourself whether you want to run a hydrogenation at 60 psi (4 bar)."? I'll wait until the bounty period is over (to maximize the attention) and then reward you the bounty :-).

Comment: @Jori I can't comment on the exact mechanism of the reduction - I don't know which intermediates are involved. Concerning the higher pressure I just wanted to point out that higher pressure involves higher risks in the case the reactor bursts! Which doesn't mean that the risks can't be handled. Back in the days I worked in a group that performed electrolysis of metals under 150 atm CO. But that was in stainless steel autoclaves and the reaction was carried out in a concrete fume hood without a solid roof but 5 cm steel doors ;)

Comment: @Jori >Can you comment on why Fe/HCl reduces the α,β-unsaturated nitroalkene to a keton instead of a saturated nitroalkane or a (un)saturated amine?  || because enamines tend to isomerize into imines that react with water producing ammonia and ketone. You should reduce the double bond first.

Comment: @permeakra Ah of course. $\ce{Fe/HCl}$ is selective for the nitro group?

Answer (score 3):

There are numerous reports on transfer hydrogenation, where hydrogen is transferred from strongly reducing agent onto double bond or other groups.

In particular, Raney nickel was utilized in reduction of both nitrogroups to amines and alkenes to alkanes, [using formic acid for the former](https://www.erowid.org/archive/rhodium/chemistry/cth.nitro2amine.rani-hcooh.html)  [and isopropanol for the latter](http://rua.ua.es/dspace/bitstream/10045/12847/4/proofs2.pdf). I guess, that combined process is also likely to work.

Answer (score 3):

$\ce{NaBH4}$ will only reduce the $\ce{RCH=CHNO2}$ to $\ce{RCH2CHNO2}$. An additional reducing agent, such as $\ce{Zn/HCl}$, can reduce the nitro group to the amine. A catalyst + $\ce{NaBH4}$ could do the whole thing, but you'll have to look at the literature.

Catalytic hydrogenation, using $\ce{Pd/C}$ under moderate conditions (around 5 bar $\ce{H2}$, 30-90 °C), can reduce $\ce{RCH=CHNO2}$ directly to  $\ce{RCH2CHNH2}$.

Comment: I have done the reduction of RCH=CHNO2 to RCH2CHNO2 using NaBH4 in the presence of column chromatography grade silica gel. It works well. Hydrogenation over Pd/C is poor giving a mixture unless you do it in the presence of ammonia.