# Can HI/P reduction be used to reduce nitroalkanes and nitroarenes to alkyl amines and aryl amines?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

> Can $\ce{HI/P}$ reduction be used to reduce nitroalkanes and
>   nitroarenes to alkyl amines and aryl amines ?

I learnt from my textbook that heating the nitroalkanes and nitroarenes with $\ce{H2}/\ce{Pt}$ is sufficient for the above conversion. But I am not sure whether $\ce{HI}$ and red $\ce{P}$ reduction will give the same products. Also, I could not find related information about this on the Internet.

Comment: Related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/21638/reduction-of-%CE%B1-%CE%B2-unsaturated-nitro-compounds

Answer (score 4):

I've never seen the $\ce{HI/P}$ method being used for the reduction of aliphatic or aromatic nitro compounds.

> I learnt from my textbook that heating the nitroalkanes and nitroarenes with $\ce{H2/Pt}$ is sufficient for the above conversion.

I've reduced a lot of nitroarenes to their corresponding amines by catalytic hydrogenation under standard conditions in ethanol (or methanol) over $\ce{Pd/C}$. In the cases I examined, heating wasn't necessary.